# How to implement a Spam Filter in LoopBack

Tags: android, loopbackjs, loopback

I am new to StackOverflow,
I'm working on an android chat app that allows the user to talk to each other via a chat interface. The backend of the app is based on loopback. I have a model, "spam list" that stores some spam words, each word being one record in the model. And this model has only one property, "word".

I want to implement a spam filter on the message sent by the user, wherein, if any word in the message matches any "word" in the "spam list", is replaced by asterisks(*), or detected at least. Since the number of words to be stored in "spam list" is not fixed, I cannot take each word from the list and check if it is present in the user's message. Can I?

Can anyone please help me in this in a more efficient manner?

Comment: please be gentle LOL..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158877/easiest-way-to-check-if-a-java-string-instance-might-hold-spam-data this may help you.

Comment: @Sree Thanks man! That helped...